# Selecting unique column for each row

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have the following table:

```
'A', '2014-07-28'
'A', '2014-07-27'
'A', '2014-07-20'
'B', '2014-07-21'
'B', '2014-07-20'
'A', '2014-07-22'
'A', '2014-07-22'
'B', '2014-07-22'
'B', '2014-07-24'
'B', '2014-07-27'
```

I need to get a report of user's login history. The report should show the number of users who logged in unique days.

So for example on 27th, A and B both logged in. Thus the report should show 2.
On 22nd, A logged in twice while B logged in once so the report should show 2.

If I select DISTINCT by user_id, then the same user on different days won't be counted.
If I select DISTINCT by date, then same days with different users won't be counted.

I want the report to count the number of unique IDs on each date. Then sum up for all the days.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You have no PK. Potentially problematic.

Comment: there's a PK, this is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to use a `Group By` Clause to get the count per day

```
Select user_id, `date`, count(*) As count
From loginTable
Group By user_id, `date`
```

Then use this another group by in a derived table to sum per user.

```
Select d.user_id, Sum(*) As TotalCount
From (
    Select user_id, `date`, count(*) As count
    From loginTable
    Group By user_id, `date`) d
Group By d.user_id
```